# Sandboxed Mac App with helper command line tool

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store, monomac, xamarin.mac

I am getting the following error when submitting my app

> Invalid Signature - the main app bundle MyApp at path MyApp.app is signed but the signature is invalid. The following error(s) were reported from codesign: a sealed resource is missing or invalid In architecture: i386

I have a small console app that lives inside Resources folder, it does not need root privileges at all. I do not have the source code of this helper so I can't rebuild it.

If I remove the console app from my bundle the error goes away.

What this command line helper app does is it takes a file process it and creates a new one based on some information passed by args.

So the question is, how can we embed command line tools to our Sandboxed app and bypass the above error? Again I don't own the source code of this helper tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had this problem and was able to solve it by signing the app myself using codesign in Terminal.

Here is how you do it:

```
codesign --entitlements path/to/.entitlementsFile -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Your Company (or whatever the name of your certificate is in your keychain)" ./TheNameOfTheTool
```

Hope that helps!